# PHP MongoDB library findOne returns nothing

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to return a single document from the database by it's ID.
This is what I have right now.

```
$id = "5a30ff2c3afc720394000ac2";
$collection = (new \MongoDB\Client(DB_HOST))->DB->posts;
$post = $collection->findOne(['_id' => $id]);
```

`findOne()` returns nothing while `find()` seems to be working. MongoDB documentations mentions that it would not return anything if no document were to be found. However, the document does seem to be in my database.

I have also tried PHP MongoDB documentation example.

```
$post = $collection->findOne(['_id' => new \MongoId($id)]);
```

This returns a no class found error.

Comment: Try: $post = $collection->findOne(['_id' => '$id']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo by default stores _id as Object

Try this

```
$collection->findOne(['_id'=> new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("$mongoId")]);
```

You are using MongoDB driver, but using Mongo driver object.